# Efficiently producing Partial Residual Plots in R

Tags: r, rstudio, glm

I have a large glm (4Gb in size) for which I would like to display the partial residual plots using `crPlots(myGLM)`

Currently RStudio hangs on displaying the first plot. The machine I'm using is decently powerful.

Is there a more efficient way to display these plots? I was thinking there might be a way to take a random sample of the residuals and display only 10% of them to get a view of the patterns.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask this question on cross validated.